# What does register mean in this context?

Tags: word-meaning

Here is the context:
A 2010 study among the Vezo showed that even five-year-old children already had a good understanding of the biological basis of death as cessation. They’re present when animals are slaughtered, are expected to attend funerals and wakes, and are obliged to look at their dead parents to ‘register’ the fact that they will never see them again. By the age of 12, these children have already started developing a robust dualistic notion of death where biological and spiritual dimensions stand together.

What does register mean in here?

reference:
Why we need to discuss a death in the family with the children | Aeon Essays

Comment: a dictionary (oxford) gives "make an impression on a person's mind."  did you find something like that in your dictionary?

Comment: No, I didn't. Thank you!

Comment: The Oxford online dictionary gives many definition of the word **register**. The definition that is appropriate in the present context is **notice something**. https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/register_1

Comment: Okay then,  that sense is sometimes included in the sense of "notice (something)" and not explicit in many learners' dictionaries.  I've voted to close as as "answerable in a dictionary" but I think this not a bad question (+1) In the future, when asking for meanings, always tell us what definitions you have found, and the dictionary that you have used.